# Function no longer accepting extra parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to script the functions from one database to another. I did not write these functions, so I don't know the original intentions. One of them is giving me some trouble. The function `GetPayDate` only accepts a single `datetime` parameter. However, when it is called:

```
SET @Minutes = (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(n, '1/1/2008', DateTime)) FROM Activities WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND dbo.GetPayDate(DateTime, Homework) = @PayDate AND ActivityTypeID = 2)
```

It is passed an extra parameter. This occurs in multiple locations. It works fine on the original database, but when I try to script it to the new one it throws:

```
Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetTotalHours, Line 8
Procedure or function dbo.GetPayDate has too many arguments specified.
```

Why would it work in one database and not the other, and what might that extra parameter be doing there in the first place?

Definition from source server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPayDate](@Date DATETIME)     RETURNS DATETIME  AS  BEGIN    DECLARE @FirstPayPeriod DATETIME  DECLARE @PayPeriodsElapsed INT  DECLARE @PayPeriod DATETIME    SET @FirstPayPeriod = '5/4/2008'  SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = 0    IF @Date IS NULL   SET @PayPeriod = NULL  ELSE    BEGIN    SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(d, @FirstPayPeriod, @Date) / 14)    IF  DATEDIFF(d, @FirstPayPeriod, @Date) % 14 > 0 SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = @PayPeriodsElapsed + 1    SET @PayPeriod = DATEADD (d, @PayPeriodsElapsed * 14, @FirstPayPeriod)    SET @PayPeriod = DATEADD (d, 5, @PayPeriod)   END    RETURN @PayPeriod    END
```

Definition from destination server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPayDate](@Date DATETIME)     RETURNS DATETIME  AS  BEGIN    DECLARE @FirstPayPeriod DATETIME  DECLARE @PayPeriodsElapsed INT  DECLARE @PayPeriod DATETIME    SET @FirstPayPeriod = '5/4/2008'  SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = 0    IF @Date IS NULL   SET @PayPeriod = NULL  ELSE    BEGIN    SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(d, @FirstPayPeriod, @Date) / 14)    IF  DATEDIFF(d, @FirstPayPeriod, @Date) % 14 > 0 SET @PayPeriodsElapsed = @PayPeriodsElapsed + 1    SET @PayPeriod = DATEADD (d, @PayPeriodsElapsed * 14, @FirstPayPeriod)    SET @PayPeriod = DATEADD (d, 5, @PayPeriod)   END    RETURN @PayPeriod    END
```

Comment: You can follow this article to view the definition of your user-defined function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189890.aspx

Comment: Is there something in particular in that definition that I should be looking at to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Can you post the definitions from both servers?

Comment: @Jim - I've edited the definitions into my question, but they are identical, as `GetPayDate` was one of the functions that was successfully scripted over.

Comment: Ok, does the function work if you just send it one parameter?  EDIT Nevermind, it looks like it works fine.  I suppose just get rid of the second parameter in your code and see what happens (probably nothing, because a second parameter isn't being used).  Was the original database from an older version of SQL Server?

Comment: When you say `It works fine on the original database`, did you try executing the SET statement and it did not throw any error in the original database? Just try running `SELECT <database_name>.dbo.GetPayDate('20120912',<Homework_datatype>)` on the original db and see what happens?

Comment: @Kash - I haven't tried it myself, but according the the senior programmer, it is used often and works. I just tried something similar; I removed the SET part, modified the SELECT statement to standalone, and removed the second parameter and it worked. Well, it executed successfully. I'm not sure whether it did what it was supposed to.

Comment: Also, are there any rows that were returned in the original database? The function may never have been executed because `WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND ActivityTypeID = 2)` excluded all rows.

Comment: @SaintWacko - [Trust no one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files). Try running the above SELECT yourself and see what happens.

Comment: @Kash - Wups, my original response was before your edit, and you posted again while I was writing my edit :)

Comment: @SaintWacko - You need to add the second parameter (dummy acceptable data for Homework) in your `SELECT` and run it on the original db bcos that would be a true test if it accepts the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @Jim - It's very likely that it was. It looks like it would work if I removed the second parameter, but I'm loathe to do that, as I don't know why it's there. There had to be some reason for it.

Comment: @Kash - The problem is, I don't know what Homework is. The only place it shows up is as the second parameter in the `GetPayDate` call. Edit: Hang on, scratch that: it's a column in a table. No, when an acceptable value is added in, the SELECT statement doesn't work on the original db either. But then how could it be successfully running? That function is being constantly used, we'd notice if it wasn't working.

Comment: Well, darn. Guess everyone is just as confused as I am.

Comment: @SaintWacko - The easiest answer is that it never worked in the first place. I doubt the WHERE would short-circuit as YuxiuLi is suggesting. It could be a source code logistics issue with source control.

Comment: @Kash - I can't imagine how it worked in the first place either, but the senior programmer says it does. Is there any way to check when that function was last called?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of your databases have `GetPayDate` with two parameters and another database have function `GetPayDate` with only one parameter. Hence the confusion.

Comment: No, they both have only one parameter. They are actually precisely identical, as `GetPayDate` was one of the functions that was scripted over.

Comment: In that case please publish the code (or at least the signature) of the function.

Comment: I've put the definition in the question, which appears to just be the code without line breaks.

Comment: Can't be in a different database else you would get a `cannot find` error because the function is being used by its 2-part name.

Answer (score 0):

Senior programmers have been known to be wrong on occasion.

The error message you got is what you should get in this circumstance. It is irrelevant if it worked before, it does not work now.  I would theorize that the function orginally had two parameters and someone changed it. (If you have properly kept your sql code in source control as it belongs like any other code, you could even tell who and when, if you haven't then this is a good time to suggest doing so as you are moving to a new database). Likely all the references to the function were not changed, just the ones the developer who made the change was working on.

As to them working in the orginal database, I would suspect they may not be, but the way they are being called may not bubble up any errors where people can see them.  Or in fact the parts of the code that someone forgot to update are not being regularly called by the application (perhaps only one branch of an IF for instance or a proc that is no longer being used). So maybe the function is being used throughout the application but in most cases it is being properly called with one parameter.

You can't see when the last time a function was called was. However, you can test the application on dev and run SQL profiler at the same time to see how the function is being called. If you use stored procs, you may first need to identify the procs that call the function and look for their execution in profiler.

All in all it doesn't matter what was happening originally, it will not work in the new database and thus the calls must be changed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. The reason I didn't want to change it was because I didn't know why it was there. I didn't want to remove code with an unknown purpose. However, the `Homework` column is a bit datatype, which hasn't been 1 since 2008, so hopefully it won't be a problem.